# error in using getelementbytag() to fetch data from a html in jsoup

Tags: javascript, html, jsoup

Hi I am trying to get data using crawling from html given below I got the entire html by following

```
Elements b= doc.getElementsByClass("a");
```

Then for getting the value from tr tag I used

```
 Elements tr = b.getElementsByTag("tr");
```

But it shows the error as T**he method getElementsByTag(String) is undefined for the type Elements**

I want to get the values for tr tag please help me in it. The html which i am working is given below,

```html
<table class="a">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <td>the<br>boy</td>
   <td>ran<br>well</td>
   <td>the<br>boy</td>
   <td>ran<br>well</td>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>6</td>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>1</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Its document.getElementsByTagName() not getElementsByTag

Comment: `jsoup` is `java` api not `javascript`

Comment: @ prakash If we give document.getElementsByTagName(), the we have to iterate through every tr tag right?

Comment: It will return you array of element object. You can iterate over it or get specific element by index.

Comment: try `Elements tr = doc.select(".a tr");`

Comment: @ParkashKumar the problem is that the html which i have posted here is actually  a sub table html, so if I get tr tag using doc it will return many tr tags including main table tag's tr also. Whereas by using the above class which belongs to table, I can easily get the tr tags right.?

Comment: No, it will return you whole table object if you do var a = document.getElementsByClassName("a");

Comment: If you can use jQuery, you can $("table.a tr") will return you tr(s) of specific table.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what we are talking about, java or javascript.

But instead of fetching first the elements with className `a` and then iterating over the result to fetch the elements with tagname `tr` you may fetch the `<tr/>`'s with a single statement.

In javascript the method would be [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```
var tr = document.querySelectorAll(".a tr");
```

In jsoup(I'm not familiar with java/jsoup, so that's just a guess) exists a method [`select`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select-java.lang.String-)

```
Elements tr = doc.select(".a tr");
```

Comment: it is java not javascript, sorry for not being specific.

Answer (score 0):

To get html elements using class and tag names

Use below code.

```
var a= document.getElementsByClassName("a");
var b= document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
```

It should work :-)

Comment: Ya, but i wont get tr tags under class a, I will get tr of whole doc that is my problem.

Comment: How about `a[0].getElementsByTagName("tr")` ?

Comment: sorry it is in java, not javascript.

Comment: To iterate through all the rows of selected tables you can use     a[0].rows